# Rails REPL that is more than irb/pry but less than rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, read-eval-print-loop

I frequently want to try out small code snippets, often much smaller than classes, and even functions, just to make sure it works by itself so I don't need to test it by running a bunch of scripts, simply to fix small errors in a line of code or so.

Besides irb/pry, I want to test Rails-specific code, such as `Object.blank?`. So with that, I want to have the Rails library loaded, but I don't need the full functionality that Rails console gives me. Especially when the application is not in a working state, the REPL will not open at all, and merely present a stack trace of the failure at hand.

If anybody knew how to achieve this middle ground, maybe through the use of a particular gem path and `require` statement to load one of the other REPLs I have mentioned, could you illustrate those commands?

I am working inside of a project using RVM to manage the gemset, and would like to not modify that environment at all, maybe only my general terminal environment, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.blank?` is from ActiveSupport. You can actually just load ActiveSupport without the rest of Rails:

```
irb(main):001:0>  require 'active_support/all'
irb(main):002:0> [].blank?
=> true
```

The [`all.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/all.rb) file loads all of ActiveSupport.

The same can be done with ActiveRecord and other rails components; for example:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'active_record'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> class NewModel < ActiveRecord::Base; end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> NewModel.new
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for NewModel
```

This gives an error because I didn't bother setting up a database, but it shows that Rails is pretty modular. I've used ActiveRecord in projects without Rails (the [`rails` gem is actually an empty gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails) which just defines the various active_* gems as dependencies).

Comment: I have also done this in `pry` and got it working, in case anyone was wondering, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Rails "magic" come from [Active Support Core Extensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html). You can include that in a regular `irb` session to get most of the connivence methods like `blank?`.

Start an IRB session and run

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```